# Execute code at timed view flip Android

Tags: android, view, timer

I am writing an app that is similar to a slide show and uses a viewflipper that flips at an interval of 5 seconds. I am new to android, and was wondering, is there any way I can execute code at every view flip? This code would update a layout object such as text in a text box.

Here is some sample code:

```
vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01); 
vf.setFlipInterval(5000);       
vf.startFlipping();`
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way built in to ViewFlipper that allows you to do that easily. It is still possible to do it a few ways though.

One option you have is to use a runnable to "run along side" of your ViewFlipper, since your interval is known you can set up a recursive runnable that will also use a 5000ms interval to make things happen at the same time as the view is changing.

```
vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01); 
vf.setFlipInterval(5000);       
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Do something here

        vf.postDelayed(r,5000);
    }
}
vf.postDelayed(r, 5000);
vf.startFlipping();
```

Another way to do it would be forego the automatic flipping via startFlipping(), and instead use a runnable like this with `vf.showNext()` inside of it. That way each iteration of the runnable will flip views for you, and you can do whatever else you want along with it.

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for your reply! This example will work perfectly.